# WF4 - Assign Out Arguments to Variables

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

It's probably to easy, that's why I can't find an answer for my question:

To assign a value from an activity out argument to a variable, I just need to set the name of the variable in the specific field of the property windows in the designer, right? No need to work with assign activities?

I'm pretty confused, because I can't assign a value of type IReadOnlyList (out arg) to object (scope variable). It won't do the casting (at design time).

But if the assignment (as assumed) goes FROM out arg TO variable it would be just regular boxing. That's why I'm not sure what WF does when I assign them both in the Designer window.

I hope I could make it clear.

Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

To assign the output of an activity to a variable you only need to set the out(or in/out) argument field to the name of the variable. The variable must have the same type as the out argument or a type that supports implicit cast to the type of the argument.